# Meaning of Down to the?

Tags: american-english, british-english, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of `down to the`?

E.g. in this statement:

> In order to use this feature, the statements must be exactly the same
>   - down to the number of spaces, tabs, capital/small letters.

My understanding of the above statement is that the statement must be exactly the same, including the number of spaces, tabs, capital/small letters.

Am I correct? If not please correct me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

The phrase 'down to' is used to convey a sense of doing something in great detail, often with the implication of a 'wider' starting point, e.g.,

> He cleaned the car from top to bottom, from washing and waxing the paintwork, down to polishing the wheels and vaccuuming the carpets

Answer (score 0):

There's also *down to the wire*, meaning that something is not completed until the very last moment (whether by procrastination, unavoidable delays, or even very close results). http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/down+to+the+wire http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/down_to_the_wire http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Down-to-The-Wire.html

For other "down to" expressions: http://esl-bits.net/idioms/id174.htm